# Turning a real variable into a complex one while integrating

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

Is it possible to turn the following real-valued integral into a complex-valued one?
$\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x(1+i)}x^{-a}dx=(1+i)^{a-1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-t}t^{-a}dt $

I mean, in the first integral, x is a real variable, while in the second one it's a complex one. When is this substitution correct?

Comment: What about the transformation of the integration bounds ?

Comment: Do you mean the upper bound? Should  it be different from what I wrote? How would this change the evaluation of the integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of $\int_0^{\infty}$, let's take $\int_0^R$.
I'll also assume $0 < a < 1$ (if $a \ge 1$ the integral diverges).
The result of performing the substitution $z=(1+i)x$ on the integral is then
$$ (1+i)^{a-1} \int_{C_1} \exp(-z)\; z^{-a}\; dz$$
where $C_1$ is the straight line from $0$ to $(1+i)R$.  Now we have
$$ \int_{C_1} \exp(-z)\; z^{-a}\; dz = \int_0^R  \exp(-z)\; z^{-a}\; dz  + \int_{C_2} \exp(-z)\; z^{-a} \; dz$$\where $C_2$ is the straight line from $R$ to $(1+i)R$.
However, on $C_2$ the integrand is bounded in absolute value by $\exp(-R) R^{-a}$, so the integral over $C_2$ is bounded in absolute value by $\exp(-R) R^{1-a}$.  Thus as $R \to \infty$, the integral over $C_2$ goes to $0$ and we do have

$$\eqalign{ \int_{0}^\infty \exp(-(1+i)x)\; x^{-a}\; dx &= (1+i)^{a-1} \lim_{R \to \infty} \exp(-z)\; z^{-a}\; dz\cr & = (1+i)^{a-1} \int_0^\infty \exp(-z)\; z^{-a}\; dz }$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Could you please explain why does the integral diverge if a>=1 ?

Comment: By comparison with $x^{-a}$ near $x=0$.

Comment: Thank you so much!